# HA-Proxy 301 re-direct: https to https://www

Tags: linux, networking, haproxy, 301-redirect

I am trying to have HA-Proxy 301 redirect an https domain. I need:

https://example.com to redirect to https://www.example.com

This is what I was trying to get it to work:

```
# corp - example.com
    redirect prefix https://www.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i example.com }
    redirect prefix https://www.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.example.com }
    acl server01 hdr_dom(host) -i www.example.com
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

**EDITED EXAMPLE OF cfg FILE (Code at bottom is part of cfg):**

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
```

defaults
    log global
    maxconn 100000
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option forwardfor
        timeout connect 600000ms
        timeout server 600000ms
    timeout client 600000ms
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend main_http_proxy
    bind *:80
    mode http
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxystatus?stats
    stats realm Strickly\ Private
    stats auth ec2ops:7is92kc81k92kds8

```
# example.com
#redirect scheme https code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.example.com } !{ ssl_fc }
#redirect prefix  https://www.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i example.com } !{ ssl_fc }
#redirect prefix https://www.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i example.com }
#redirect prefix https://www.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.example.com }
acl no_WWW hdr(host) -i example.com
redirect prefix www.example.com code 301 if no_WWW


# Backend Rules
use_backend SERVER01 if jcma01
use_backend SERVER01 if no_WWW
```

frontend main_https_proxy
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/pem/
    mode http
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    acl secure dst_port eq 443
    rsprep ^Set-Cookie:\ (.*) Set-Cookie:\ \1;\ Secure if secure
    rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=31536000 if secure

`use_backend SERVER01 if { ssl_fc_sni www.example.com }
#use_backend SERVER01 if { ssl_fc_sni example.com }`

backend server01
    balance source
    cookie SERVER01 insert
    server SERVER01 10.10.10.10:80 cookie SERVER01 check inter 5s

Comment: With the current config, does the 'www' URL rewrite work (without any HTTPS redirects)?  Does HTTPS redirection work (without the 'www' URL rewrite)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got those ACLs, wouldn't

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

or

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if {hdr(host) -i yourdomain.example.com } !{ ssl_fc }
```

be a cleaner solution?

Comment: That would work with non-https redirects, but when you explicitly go to 'https ://example.com', it does not redirect to 'https ://www.example.com'.

Comment: Ah, I reread the question, and I understand now.  Why not separate the redirect for www and the HTTPS redirect.  Add  ' acl no_WWW hdr(host) -i  example.com' and 'redirect prefix http://www.example.com code 301 if no_WWW'

Comment: Hey Jim, I really appreciate the help, would you mind elaborating? Im still confused. Where is that code you suggested supposed to be placed exactly?

Comment: Can you post a full redacted config?  That will make things easier.

Comment: Sure, Ill edit my original question with it.

Comment: I think I may have got it working. I added this:

redirect prefix https://www.example.com code 301 if { ssl_fc_sni example.com }

I had to add it after backend rules, so HA-Proxy gives me a warning. 

Do you know if this is ok? Any other method you think would be better? 

Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but now the answer can be found in the Haproxy official documentation:

```
frontend www
   bind :443
   acl has_www hdr_beg(host) -i www
   http-request redirect  code 301  location https://www.%[hdr(host)]%[capture.req.uri]  unless has_www
   use_backend webservers
```

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/traffic-routing/redirects/#redirect-traffic-to-a-location